# How to profile a cron task in Magento

Tags: magento, cron, profiler

I have a cron task in Magento that I need to profile to determine memory usage problems. The script runs during the night, and crashes after half an hour or so due to consuming all available memory.

I need to profile the script to determine which functions are consuming too much memory.

I have tried using the [Aoe_Profiler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-profiler.html), but when trying to profile a cron task, there is nowhere to view the output, as the cron task does not invoke the MVC, thus the profiler's view block can't be rendered.

How can a cron task be profiled in Magento?

Comment: Why did you ask a question and then answer it within the same minute?

Comment: See this link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.  It's something that took a bit of work to get right, and I thought I'd like to share.

Comment: I do appreciate the sharing, just never seen it asked and answered within the same minute before - so just thought I'd try and get your reasoning, and that SE blog answers my question perfectly. :) (Thought, since I have yet to ask a question here, can you not accept your own answer?)

Comment: It appears you can (you don't get rep for it though.). I was waiting to see if anyone else had any input on this topic. BTW, when you ask a question, you have the option to answer it straight away. This stops the question from being submitted until you have finished the answer.

Comment: Haha, nice! That is good to know, thank you. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'trick' we have used from time to time in running and debugging/testing cron scripts from the command line is to copy `cron.php` that lives in the root folder of the Magento application to a new script that represents the cron task that you wish to execute, eg `xyz_cron_task.php`.

Down the bottom of that script is a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```

This can be changed as follows, to run just the cron task you're interested in:

```
try {
    Mage::getModel('your_module/cron')->yourCronTask();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```

Now the cron task can be executed from the command line, or the browser. You can visit the page `http://yourdomain/xyz_cron_task.php`, and the cron task will be executed (although you won't see anything interesting yet).

To get the profiling working (assuming you have already enabled profiling in the Admin section), add the following code after `require 'app/Mage.php';`:

```
Varien_Profiler::enable(); // This enables profiling
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); // This allows you to see exceptions etc, but not stricly required.
```

This will enable profiling, but you still won't see the profiler output, as there is no view model to render it.

You can output the profiler block by adding one line to the `try/catch` block as follows:

```
try {
    Mage::getModel('harmony/cron')->importProductsAndStock();

    // The following line outputs the profiler block.
    echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock("core/profiler")->toHtml();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```

You should now see the profiler output as follows (assuming you're using the [Aoe_Profiler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-profiler.html) extension):

[image]

Now you can the appropriate `Varien_Profiler::start()/stop()` code to your cron task as required.

Happy profiling!